# Spring Autoconfiguration failing with JsonTest

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

Using [spring and its testing utilities](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html), I want to create a slice test to check the serialization of my model.

There are the dependencies that I'm using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Using the following test class, I do not manage to autowire my JacksonTester and receive a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException exception:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.json.JsonTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.json.JacksonTester;
import org.springframework.boot.test.json.JsonContent;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@JsonTest
public class MyTest
{
    @Autowired
    private JacksonTester<MyClass> tester;

    @Test
    public void myTest()
    {
        // test logic
    }
}
```

and the trace:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2018-03-29 17:25:35.319  INFO 3480 --- [           main] MyTest                     : Starting MyTest on Laptop.local with PID 3480 (started by Matt in /path/to/project)
2018-03-29 17:25:35.322  INFO 3480 --- [           main] MyTest                     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-03-29 17:25:35.334  INFO 3480 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1e13529a: startup date [Thu Mar 29 17:25:35 BST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-29 17:25:35.843  INFO 3480 --- [           main] MyTest                     : Started MyTest in 0.756 seconds (JVM running for 1.778)



============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   JacksonAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   JsonTestersAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.assertj.core.api.Assert'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.test.jsontesters.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   JsonTestersAutoConfiguration.JacksonJsonTestersConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   NoOpCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.NoOpCacheConfiguration NONE cache type (CacheCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   CacheAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   CacheAutoConfiguration.CacheManagerJpaDependencyConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' (OnClassCondition)
         - Ancestor org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration did not match (ConditionEvaluationReport.AncestorsMatchedCondition)

   CaffeineCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine', 'org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   CouchbaseCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket', 'com.couchbase.client.spring.cache.CouchbaseCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   EhCacheCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'net.sf.ehcache.Cache', 'org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   GenericCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.GenericCacheConfiguration unknown cache type (CacheCondition)

   GsonAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.google.gson.Gson' (OnClassCondition)

   HazelcastCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance', 'com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   InfinispanCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.infinispan.spring.provider.SpringEmbeddedCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   JCacheCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.cache.Caching', 'org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JodaDateTimeJacksonConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder', 'org.joda.time.DateTime', 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.ser.DateTimeSerializer', 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.cfg.JacksonJodaDateFormat' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.ParameterNamesModuleConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule' (OnClassCondition)

   JsonTestersAutoConfiguration.GsonJsonTestersConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.google.gson.Gson' (OnClassCondition)

   JsonTestersAutoConfiguration.JacksonJsonTestersConfiguration#jacksonTesterFactoryBean:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper (OnBeanCondition)

   JsonTestersAutoConfiguration.JsonbJsonTesterConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.json.bind.Jsonb' (OnClassCondition)

   JsonbAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.json.bind.Jsonb' (OnClassCondition)

   RedisCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration unknown cache type (CacheCondition)

   SimpleCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.SimpleCacheConfiguration unknown cache type (CacheCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    None



2018-03-29 17:25:35.858 ERROR 3480 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.TestContextManager               : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@f73dcd6] to prepare test instance [MyTest@5c87bfe2]

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'MyTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tester'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.test.json.JacksonTester<MyClass>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:400) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460) [.cp/:?]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206) [.cp/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.test.json.JacksonTester<MyClass>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 29 more

2018-03-29 17:25:35.869  INFO 3480 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1e13529a: startup date [Thu Mar 29 17:25:35 BST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
```

Per documentation, it doesn't seem like any other configuration is required as with the JsonTest annotation, spring should autoconfigure everything I need which is only the JacksonTester in my case. However, I can see that there are some Negative Matches in the configuration especially for JsonTestersAutoConfiguration.

Am I missing some spring config? Is there any dependency missing? or any dependency incompatibility?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no `ObjectMapper` bean in the context which prevents any `JacksonTester`s from being created. You can see this in the auto-configuration report:

```
JsonTestersAutoConfiguration.JacksonJsonTestersConfiguration#jacksonTesterFactoryBean:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper (OnBeanCondition)
```

There's no `ObjectMapper` bean in the context as its auto-configuration uses `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` to create the `ObjectMapper` and `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`, which is part of `spring-web`, isn't on the classpath.

You can fix the problem by replacing your Jackson dependencies with a dependency on Spring Boot's JSON starter. That would leave your pom looking like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

It's not related to this particular problem, but if you're using Spring Boot's dependency management (by using `spring-boot-starter-parent` as your pom's parent, for example), you should remove the versions from both dependencies and allow the parent's dependency management to set them.

Comment: I naively thought it was part of the starter-test. Thanks for pointing out it was part of spring-web. For your advice, I'm actually using the spring-boot-dependencies dependency in the dependency management section as I'm using another parent already. This was a snippet code where I was trying to isolate an issue I'm having with my main project and I wanted the minimal set of dependency for this snippet. Thanks, you avoided me a headache.